# React - object assign multiple dynamic input values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I am trying to set state of dynamically generated inputs. The initial **tasks** object where I want to set the new state looks like so:

[image]

**The render method:**

```js
    render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <main className="content">
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

            <div>
              {Object.keys(this.state.dataGoal).map( (key, index) => {
                  return <div key={key}>
                            <label>{this.state.dataGoal[key]}</label>

                            <div className="input-wrap">

                                <input
                                  type="text"
                                  name={`${key}-task-${index}`}
                                  value={this.state.tasks[key]}
                                  onChange={this.handleInputChange} />

                            </div>
                         </div>;
              })}
            </div>

            <div className="input-wrap">
               <input
                 className="primary-btn"
                 type="submit"
                 value="Set my goal!"
                 onClick={this.formReset} />
             </div>
           </form>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**and finally the handleInputChanged function:**

```js
  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const name = e.target.name;

    this.setState({
      tasks: Object.assign({}, this.state.tasks, {[name]: value})
    });
  }
```

I want to set the new state of object when one of the inputs is changed. The desired result is to get the input value and set it to **name** key as an value in **tasks** object.

I also want to ask if the input names must be unique.

Thanks for any help,
Jakub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you're on the right path, the only thing missing is we will have to tell `handleInputChange` what index we want to update in tasks. We will have to use `Object.assign` twice because it's a nested structure. In this case if we assume the indices of `dataGoal` match up with `tasks`, we can pass in the index provided by the map function.

In our render function:

```
<input
       type="text"
       name={`${key}-task-${index}`}
       value={this.state.tasks[key]}
       onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e, index)} /> 

// Notice: This will cause a performance hit
// We are binding 'this' using fat arrow every render but it shows the idea
```

Handling the input:

```
  handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const name = e.target.name;
    const tasks = this.state.tasks;
    const updatedTask = Object.assign({}, tasks[index], { [name]: value });

    this.setState({
      tasks: Object.assign({}, tasks, { [index]: updatedTask })
    });
  }
```

Input names don't have to be unique in this case, as the index will provide 'uniqueness'.

---

Using destructing instead of Object.assign:

```
  handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const name = e.target.name;

    this.setState({
      tasks: {
          ...this.state.tasks,
          [index]: {
             ...this.state.tasks[index],
             [name]: value
          }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You have made my day. :) I just really need to digest it.